# Local Experiences seems to be missing in iOS 15.4

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

After upgrading to iOS 15.4 it seems like "Local experiences" are missing in the developer section.
Has it been moved elsewhere? Or do I need to test my app clips in another way?
Best regards, Ole